# Integrability and convergence of $e^{-t} \cos(\ln t)$ as $t \to 0^+$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

In [this blackpenredpen video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9l1E-KhXC4#t=4m10s) for $i!$ he obtains

$$i! = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \cos(\ln t) \rm{dt} + i\int_0^\infty e^{-t} sin(\ln t) \rm{dt}$$

At 4:10 claims that these converge at $t=0$ but then he sketches a graph of $e^{-t} \cos(\ln t)$ which looks like it does *not* converge at $0$.

Can you give a better explanation please?

Comment: For the integrals to converge there is no need for the integrands to have a limit at $0$. The integrals are both convergent because $e^{-t}$ is, and $|\cos x| \leq 1, |\sin x |\leq 1$.

Comment: You can bound both $\cos$ and $\sin$ by $1$, and we know that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,dt$ converges. You just have to argue that the infinite oscillations at $0$ and $\infty$ cancel themselves out.

Comment: That makes sense to me at $t=\infty$ but not at $t=0$.